# Apply css to all elements other than first using ngfor

Tags: html, css, angular, styles, ngfor

I want to apply CSS to all elements except the first
Below is my code and the screenshot of how I want and how I am currently getting

[image] --Current

[image] --Expected

Code

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="cell col-md-4">Fann dial readings:</div>
      <div class="cell value caption-bold col-md-2  " ngclass="{'col-md-offset-1' : !$first}" *ngFor='let r of mudCheckWorksheet.rheologyTemperatures'>{{r.t}}°F</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `first as $first` in your `ngFor`:

```
 *ngFor='let r of mudCheckWorksheet.rheologyTemperatures; first as $first'
```

Check more here: [NgFor#local-variables](https://angular.io/api/common/NgFor#local-variables)

Comment: <div class="cell value caption-bold col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 "  *ngFor='let r of mudCheckWorksheet.rheologyTemperatures; first as $first'>{{r.t}}°F</div>
after the above change do i need to add if condition to apply css to all elements other than 1st?

Comment: <div class="cell value caption-bold col-md-2 " [ngClass]="{'offset-md-1' : !$First }"*ngFor="let r of mudCheckWorksheet.rheologyTemperatures; first as $First"   > {{r.t}}°F</div> worked!